# AngularJS - Error migrating from 1.2.9 to 1.4.9

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm newbie to AngularJs and when I try to use version 1.4.9 of Angular instead of 1.2.9 (that i used with no problem) i get error. I read about the need of declare new function in this way:

```
    angular.module('scotchApp', []).controller('prenotazioneController', [function ($scope) {
    //$scope.message = 'Pagina Delle info!!!';//
}]);
```

instead of:

```
function getTask($scope, $http, Base64) {
//do something
};
```

**But i got always this error:**

> Error: ng:areq
>   Bad Argument --- 
>   Argument 'mainController' is not a function, got undefined

I think the error refer to this code, but i already changed the way i declare the function.

**In JS:**

```
    // create the module and name it scotchApp
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
scotchApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'view/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    // route for the about page
    .when('/prenotazione', {
        templateUrl: 'view/prenotazione.html',
        controller: 'prenotazioneController'
    })

    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'view/login.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
    });
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
angular
    .module('scotchApp', [])
    .controller('mainController', [function ($scope) {
        // create a message to display in our view
         $scope.message = 'Vai alla Prenotazione';
    }]);

angular.module('scotchApp', []).controller('prenotazioneController', [function ($scope) {
    /*   $scope.message = 'Pagina Delle info!!!';*/
}]);

angular.module('scotchApp', []).controller('loginController', [function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = '*Necessario per eseguire una prenotazione';
}]);
```

**In HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="scotchApp">

<head>
    <!-- SCROLLS -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400italic,400,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- SPELLS -->

<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script></head>
```

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button>

                <a class="navbar-brand">
                    <img class="hidden-xs" src="image/logo.png" alt="">
                    <img class="visible-xs" src="image/logo.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="main">

        <!-- angular templating -->
        <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
        <div ng-view></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referencing the `app` module incorrectly:

**Your code:**

```
angular.module('scotchApp', [])
    .controller(...)
```

By using the `angular.module('scotchApp', [])` with the brackets **[ ]** you are essentially overwriting your app module every time.

**Change it to this:**

```
angular
   .module('scotchApp')
   .controller(...)
```

You only need to create the app module **once** and then reference it.

**Creating a module:**

```
angular.module("app", []); // creates a module.
```

**Referencing a module:**

```
angular.module("app");    // reference a module.
```

Here is a simple example below:

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module("app", []);

    app.controller("MainController", MainController);

    MainController.$inject = ["$http"];

    function MainController($http) {

    }

})();
```

Here is a [Plnkr Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/lXRKXafhnHYcXzoNEeed?p=preview) using your style of code. Hope this helps and clarify a few things.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried to delete [] from `angular.module('scotchApp', [])` but same the error appear... I also tried to use this:

`(function () {

     angular
         .module("scotchApp")
         .controller("mainController", mainController);

     mainController.$inject = ["$scope"];

     function mainController($scope) {
         $scope.message = 'Vai alla Prenotazione';
     };

 });`

but no lucky.

Comment: @Luke do you have the code somewhere we can look at or is this proprietary code?

Comment: @Luke I went ahead and made a plunkr example for you. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your plunkr! Yes it help much to better understand! They changed many things!

**But if I, instead of this (for example):**

 `scotchApp
        .controller("MainController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
            $scope.message = "Vai alla Prenotazione"    ;
        }]);`

**have this:**

`.controller('InstanziateProcess', [function ($scope, $http, $window, Base64) {...}`

**it will be:**

 `scotchApp
        .controller("InstanziateProcess", ["$scope", "$http", ""$window", "Base64", function($scope, $http, $window, Base64) {...}]);` ? **Thanks again**

Comment: @Luke Yes you are correct, you need to tell Angular the `service dependencies` you want to inject, so `$scope` and `$http` etc.. needs to be included. My example shown in the answer is using John Papa's style guide as it is fairly well known and regarded. Here is a link to it, the angular team backs him on it. https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: Thanks again! I opened a new Question for another problem 
created after changing the code, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011384/angualrjs-controller-visibility.

if you can take a look it will be appreciated.

Comment: @Luke people are already on to it, have a look at their advice.