# AngualrJS - controller visibility

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I migrated with some problem form angular 1.2.9 to 1.4.9. I do many changes in my code and now i dont understand why a function declared in a controller isn't visible to other controller anymore, where am i wrong?

In detail this is the error:

> ReferenceError: getCookie is not defined

And the code interested is this

**JS:**

```
 scotchApp
    .controller('setCookie', function (cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    });
//end save cookie

//for read global variable
scotchApp
    .controller('getCookie', function (cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
        return "";
    });
//end read cookie

scotchApp
    .controller('ControllerForm', ["$scope", "$window", "$http", "Base64", function ($scope, $window, $http, Base64) {

        $http.get("/activiti-rest/service/runtime/tasks") //necessario per prendermi l'id del processo
            .then(function (response, data, status, headers, config) {
                var currentProcessId = getCookie("currentProcessId"); 

               {........}
            });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a factory with exposed method which set/get's cookies. Surely don't need to make then controllers. Here's an example

```
scotchApp
    .factory('cookieFactory', [function(){
        return {
            setCookie : function (cname, cvalue, exdays) {
                var d = new Date();
                d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
                document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
            },

            getCookie: function (cname) {
                var name = cname + "=";
                var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                    var c = ca[i];
                    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
                    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
                return "";
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Inject the `cookieFactory` in your controller then access these methods

```
scotchApp
    .controller('ControllerForm', ["$scope", "$window", "$http", "Base64", 
    "cookieFactory",
    function ($scope, $window, $http, Base64,
        cookieFactory) {

        $http.get("/activiti-rest/service/runtime/tasks") //necessario per prendermi l'id del processo
            .then(function (response, data, status, headers, config) {
                var currentProcessId = cookieFactory.getCookie("currentProcessId"); 

               {........}
            });
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for help to understand problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should not turn `set/getCookie` functions into controllers, it doesn't make any sense for this application. Instead, it feels like they should be part of some reusable service:

```
scotchApp.factory('cookies', function() {
    return {
        set: function() { /*...*/ },
        get: function() { /*...*/ }
    };
});
```

Then inject this service into `ControllerForm` and use it:

```
scotchApp
    .controller('ControllerForm', ["$scope", "$window", "$http", "Base64", "cookies", function ($scope, $window, $http, Base64, cookies) {

        $http.get("/activiti-rest/service/runtime/tasks") //necessario per prendermi l'id del processo
            .then(function (response, data, status, headers, config) {
                var currentProcessId = cookies.get("currentProcessId"); 

               {........}
            });
}])
```

Comment: Thanks for simply and fast reply i solved! Satpal give me the same answer you gave to me only with more detail. That's why i put green flag to him. :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your get and set cookie controllers were meant to just be functions. The simplest change would just be to move them inside "ControllerForm". Then they will be in the same scope, and should get rid of the missing reference error.

```
scotchApp
    .controller('ControllerForm', ["$scope", "$window", "$http", "Base64", function ($scope, $window, $http, Base64) {

     function getCookie(cname){
     ...
     }

    function setCookie (cname, cvalue, exdays){
     ...
     }

    $http.get("/activiti-rest/service/runtime/tasks") //necessario per prendermi l'id del processo
            .then(function (response, data, status, headers, config) {
                var currentProcessId = getCookie("currentProcessId"); 

               {........}
            });
}]);
```